# How to find the maxValue's line number in one loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

here's the code:
**Tips how to simplify the code are welcome**

```
eqlCounter = 0
octals = []
with open("D:\matura\Matura2017\Dane_PR2\liczby.txt", "r") as f: #file contains 2 sets of numbers(1st decimal, second octal)
    for x in f:
        lines = f.readline()
        splited = lines.split()
        toInt = int(splited[1], 8) #oct to int(dec)
        octals.append(toInt)
        if int(splited[0]) == toInt:
            eqlCounter += 1
    print("same nmbrs: ", eqlCounter) #a
    print("min: ", min(octals),"at: ")
    print("max: ", max(octals),"at: ")
```

I would like to find a position of the line that contains the max value(already found that value)
I know i can just use another loop to find the placement, but i wonder if there's a shorter and more efficient way to do it

Comment: You might be interested in Numpys [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to ready a data file directly into a Numpy array. Then you have the function min max and where at your hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method to find the position of a value in an iterable: `index`.

```
low = min(octals)
print("min: ", low ,"at: ", octals.index(low))
```

Another possibility is to track the extremes and their positions as you iterate through the file.  For instance:

```
low = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
with ...
    for idx, x in enumerate(f):
        if toInt < low:
            low = toInt
            low_pos = idx
```

Treat the high element similarly.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work. It says that the smallest number is placed in line 187, whereas the smallest number that i checked manually is placed at the end, in line 376. I have already tried this method before, after quick google search. Although the second works just fine i will try to find something even shorter, so far its the best tho, thanks!

Comment: In that case, please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.  I made some assumption that doesn't apply to your actual data ... which you've hidden from us.

Comment: I have just made another post about it

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the greatest value, you can have 2 variables. One stores the greatest value seen so far, and the other the position of that value. Initialize both to 0. Then, every loop, check if the current number is greater than the greatest value so far, and if so, update the greatest value so far, as well as the position. Something like this should work:

```
eqlCounter = 0
octals = []
greatestSoFar = 0
greatestPos = 0
curPos = 0
with open("D:\matura\Matura2017\Dane_PR2\liczby.txt", "r") as f: #file contains 2 sets of numbers(1st decimal, second octal)
    for x in f:
        lines = f.readline()
        splited = lines.split()
        toInt = int(splited[1], 8) #oct to int(dec)
        octals.append(toInt)
        if int(splited[0]) == toInt:
            eqlCounter += 1

        # check if the current number is greater than greatestSoFar
        if toInt > greatestSoFar :
            greatestSoFar = toInt # update position and value of greatest so far
            greatestPos = curPos
        curPos += 1 # increment position counter

    print("same nmbrs: ", eqlCounter) #a
    print("min: ", min(octals),"at: ")
    print("max: ", max(octals),"at: ", str(greatestPos)) # print position of greatest value
```

This same design can be repeated to find the position of the smallest value as well.